# Sticky footer not working in Firefox when using a table display

Tags: html, css, firefox, footer

I am using the sticky footer technique outlined in [this](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) post in my website. For 90% of the pages on my site the sticky footer works perfectly. In the other 10% of pages I am running into an interesting issue in Firefox. Essentially in these pages I want to center the content of my page vertically so I am adjusting the CSS code in the post as so:

```
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    }

    .wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
    display: table; /* <--- THE NEW LINE OF CODE */
    }

    .footer, .push {
    height: 4em;
    }
```

This allows me to vertically center the div inside of `.wrapper` by simply assigning it to the following class:

```
.table_row {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

In Safari, Chrome, etc., the sticky footer remains placed at the bottom of the page and the content is nicely centered vertically. In Firefox, however, the sticky footer is place immediately following the content causing the content to get squished to the top of the page below the header. Here is a sample of what the HTML might look like in this situation:

```
     <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="table_row"><p>Your website content here.</p></div>
                <div class="push"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TY65A/1/) is its JSFiddle.

I have tried adjusting heights, min-heights, etc. in CSS but have had no luck. At this point I am at a complete loss on a solution so any help or guidance is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove **`height: auto !important;`** line and it will work.

Comment: This does cause the footer to get pushed back to the bottom of the page, however it removes the "sticky" aspect of the footer. If the page is scrolled or extends past the bottom of the window the footer is in the wrong location and stays there.

Comment: Well I tried your original code it doesn't have "sticky aspect" you are saying even in chrome... It is behaving the same with or without `height: auto !important;` Chrome 29

Comment: Interesting, I am in Chrome 35 and it works fine. If you load the JSFiddle page and then adjust the height of chrome the footer doesn't move? Where is it located on the "page"?

Comment: It does move, it is on the bottom of the page, but it's right there even if you remove this line I'm saying.

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry. The page I tested it on must have it's own issues because by chance it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Personally I had `height: auto` and just had to replace it with `height: 100%`...this was driving me nuts. Worked in everything but Firefox.